# Download an app's hidden application data on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-api

I have full access to my Google Account, and it contains hidden application data. I would like to download said data to my computer for manual review.

I know this is not possible to do easily, but 'hacky' solutions are completely fine. I desperately need this application data and would be grateful for any solution or hint.

[image: Application data to download]

Comment: The answer should include https://developers.google.com/google-apps/ or some subpage as reference, I think.

Comment: I think that this question is too-broad. Why do you posted the question here instead of Stack Overflow? I know that you are expecting the simplest solution but I have doubts that this could be done with an bookmarklet or a basic Google Apps Script. How about your "programming-fu"? What search keywords do you tried for googling about this?

Comment: @Rubén I am definitely not expecting the "simplest solution" - any solution would suffice.

Comment: Still the question looks too-broad.

Comment: @Rubén I truly don't want to contradict, but I don't see how this question is "too broad" or belongs on the wrong site. It is not strictly a programming question (even if a potential answer could use code) and is about the Google Drive _web app_, thus I think it belongs on webapps.se. It is not broad in the sense that I ask a specific question on how to do a specific task and specify that answers may be as elaborate as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

Download your data - 
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en

On reflection, the above may just be data from google products.

Have you looked at using adb to access the android backup framework?
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html#TestingRestore

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bmgr.html

Comment: Would this also export application data?

Comment: Ah, I see, just spotted the screenshot with whatsapp icon in your question. I had not noticed the android connection. I think the above may just be for google drive etc, but you could try it

Comment: What do you need to _do_ with the application data?

Comment: I need to have a literal copy of it as a file / folder on my system

Comment: I'll have a look at the two links you provided. I do have access to adb.

Comment: Nevermind... `bmgr` does not work.
Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/4603eea305822b3c18731541111c160d

Answer (score 0):

You will need python 3 and this script https://github.com/EliteAndroidApps/WhatsApp-GD-Extractor . If done successfully you will be able to download all whatsapp data from google drive to your desktop. Try their other repositories too it will help decrypt data.